# Pass choice parameters to downstream job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have an upstream job where user should be able to choose which stage to execute from a downstream job, but I'm struggling with correct syntax to pass these values on at a build job stage. I haven't found a solution to pass choise parameters to build.

I've created choices

```
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'ACTION',
            choices: ["Stop", "Deploy"],
            description: 'Choose whether to stop or deploy services'
            )
        }
```

And then based on those values the downstream job would execute the concurrent stage

```
      stage('Stop') {
         when {
              expression { params.ACTION == 'STOP' }
         }
            steps {`
```

Now I would like to pass these values at the build phase, but here I'm lost

```
                             echo "You chose: ${params.ACTION}"
                                build job: 'stage/{app}', parameters: "WHICH_ACTION=${params.ACTION}"),
```

The error I get is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep.setParameters() expects java.util.List<hudson.model.ParameterValue> but received class java.lang.String
    at
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the relevant parameter in top-level job is named `ACTION` while the parameter in the downstream job is named `WHICH_ACTION`, you may want to try this:

```
echo "You chose: ${params.ACTION}"
build job: '<downstream job name>', parameters: [
   string(name: "WHICH_ACTION", value: params.ACTION),
]
```